# How to connect the socket server running on docker container from the docker host

Tags: docker, sockets

I have "Docker for Windows" on my machine Windows 10.

I start selenium grid with docker as below:

```
docker run -d --name my-hub selenium/hub
docker run -d --name my-firefox -e HUB_HOST=my-hub -v c:/seleniumplus:/dev/seleniumplus selenium/node-firefox
docker run -d --name my-chrome -e HUB_HOST=my-hub -v c:/seleniumplus:/dev/seleniumplus selenium/node-chrome
```

I get the IP address of container "my-firefox" and "my-chrome", they are 172.17.0.3 and 172.17.0.4

```
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" my-firefox
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" my-chrome
```

I can ping the IP 172.17.0.3 and 172.17.0.4 from the docker host (my machine Windows 10).

I run a socket server on container "my-firefox" at port 9876, then I try to make a socket connection to the server by creating `new Socket(172.17.0.3, 9876)` from the docker host (my machine Windows 10), this fails with error
***Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect***

Does anyone know what is wrong with it? How can get it work? I don't want to use the port-forwarding, yes we can map the container's port 9876 to the docker host's port (for example 9876) as below:

```
docker run -d -p 9876:9876 --name my-firefox -e HUB_HOST=my-hub -v c:/seleniumplus:/dev/seleniumplus selenium/node-firefox
```

Then we can make the connection by `new Socket("localhost", 9876)`

By the way, I make some other tests:
I run a socket server on container "my-firefox" at port 9876, then I try to make a socket connection to (172.17.0.3, 9876) from the other container "my-chrome" (172.17.0.4) and it succeeds.

I run a socket server on docker host (my machine Windows 10 whose IP is 172.27.20.204) at port 9876, then I try to make a socket connection to (172.27.20.204, 9876) from a container ("my-chrome" or "my-firefox") and it succeeds.

Comment: _I don't want to use the port-forwarding_ Why not ?

Comment: If we use the "port forwarding", we have to use different port (to avoid the port conflicts on the local machine)  for multiple servers running in container. Yes, we can use the same port to run the server on container, but we have to map it to different port on the local machine. If we can use the container's IP and a port to connect the server, we just need to detect the container's IP then we can use a default port to connect the server.